# How to make my apache to support subdomains?

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am trying to do a multisite in wordpress and i created two sites in it with different subdomains. The issue is that i now need to modify my hosts file and httpd-vhosts.conf to make my apache support my subdomains.

mi archivo hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 local.wptraining.web
127.0.0.1 mx.local.wptraining.web
127.0.0.1 arg.local.wptraining.web
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wp-training"
    ServerName local.wptraining.web
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a "wildcard" name resolution that simply resolves all "subdomain names" (actually host names within a domain) to the same address:

```
127.0.0.1 *.example.com
```

And you can use the "default host" feature apache offers: the virtual host that is configured *first* (first as in time which is why it is often defined in files named "000.conf" ir similar) responds to all requests to the server where no matching vhost can be identified by `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. You still have the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` values at hand which name the actually requested host name ("subdomain").

Both aspects allow to have a static setup of name resolution and host definition while still being able to use arbitrary host names in requests which can get mapped to individual folders in the file system or sites inside a multisite CMS installation.